# I have a container-fluid that isn't extended across the whole screen even though it should be

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure out why this is.

My code is as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="text-align:center"><a href="http://www.leagueofassassins.co.uk">
            <img class="banner" src="../images/logos/Logo%20for%20LoA.png"></a>
    </div>

    <!--Navbar Begin-->
    <nav class="navbar-static-top navbar-inverse navbar-inner navbar-custom" role="navigation">

        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>-->
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="http://www.leagueofassassins.co.uk">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.leagueofassassins.co.uk/info/information.html">Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.leagueofassassins.co.uk/roster/">Roster</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.warcraftlogs.com/guilds/81546/">WarcraftLogs</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="http://www.leagueofassassins.co.uk/apply/">Apply</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Navbar End-->
```

For some reason, it leaves a big area at the right hand side when vertical but works when my phone is horizontal. I have included pictures below. Any help would be appreicated. I want it to be full screen width.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Ignore the well at the bottom with the overflowing text, please. That's not the problem.

See http://www.leagueofassassins.co.uk/apply/

Comment: If I am not wrong, this is the `<div class="container-fluid"> ... </div>` that is wrapping the whole `<nav></nav>`.

Comment: I'm wanting the .container-fluid to wrap the whole nav in order to keep the banner above it. I'll test removing it and see if it works now. EDIT: Removing that did not rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I'd accidentally missed some padding on either side of .container-custom and the bottom content was spilling over causing the page to need to be widened. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "main-pane" cals got 60% width, try removing it and it should work fine.

CSS Class

```
.main-pane {
margin-top: 1%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
width: 60%;  // remove this line
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The .main-pane class is declared well after the original nav bar has finished being created. I've removed it on the off chance that it'd help but it hasn't, unfortunately.